# How to add sub dimensions in schema workbench

Tags: pentaho, workbench

My data warehouse has snowflake schema and I am trying to create a cube for this schema. But I don't know how to add sub dimension. I am new to this and I am really confused with hierarchies and levels. This is my data warehouse:

```
ratings-fact_table   ---->   books_dm               ----> authors
    rating_id                  book_id                       author_id
    book_id                    author_id                
    user_id                    publisher_id         ----> publishers
                                                             publisher_id
       |
    users_dm   ----> cities   ---------> countries
       user_id          city_id             country_id
       city_id          country_id
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your data warehouse is build on the top of some relational database (MySQL, etc.). You can solve this problem by converting the *snowflake schema* to *star schema* manually ~ by creating *SQL views* in your database. Then in your OLAP schema you would use those tables:

- **Fact table (cube):** `ratings-fact_table`
- **Dimension table:** `books_dm_view`
- **Dimension table:** `users_dm_view`

Where:

- **`books_dm_view` is SQL view:**

  ```
  CREATE VIEW books_dm_view AS 
  SELECT * FROM books_dm b 
  LEFT JOIN authors a ON b.author_id = a.author_id 
  LEFT JOIN publishers p ON p.publisher_id = b.publisher_id
  ```
- **`users_dm_view` is SQL view:**

  ```
  CREATE VIEW users_dm_view AS 
  SELECT * FROM users_dm u 
  LEFT JOIN cities c ON c.city_id = u.city_id 
  LEFT JOIN countries n on n.country_id = c.country_id`
  ```

This way your dimensions have no sub-dimensions and you don't need to use extra joins in you OLAP schema.

Comment: Thank you very much, @mzy! Very nice solution.